# Why is the largest unsigned 64-bit binary number 18,446,744,073,709,551,615?

Tags: data-structures, unsigned-integer

something stuck on my mind says that the largest number that can be defined in 64 bits is
2 ^ 64-1, ie 18,446,744,073,709,551,615, but I know the integer is 4 bytes, not 1 byte. Does this largest number have another meaning?

Comment: What do you mean, "4 bytes, not 1 byte"?  A 64-bit integer needs 8 bytes.  I don't know what kind of "meaning" you're looking for.

Comment: i mean for example i create an integer and it is 8 bytes,i think i create (2^64 bytes)/8 bytes integer not just 2^64,i can not understand it.

Comment: Your last comment doesn't make much sense to me. There are 2^64 combinations with 64 bits. Starting with zero then you would end at 2^64-1 as the largest (when using them to represent positive integers) as a sequence of all ones.

Comment: i say there are 2^32-1 combinations with 32 bits but i can not store integer values 0 to 2^32 -1 in 4 gb RAM right ?

Comment: Sure you can. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: Because 4gb=4294967296 byte and if any integer value takes 4 byte in 32-bit,they takes (2^32-1)*4 and so it equal to more than 4 gb. I know i am wrong but i did not get what is it ?

Comment: If you address the bytes individually then 32 bits can refer to ~4.3 billion discrete byte values. Yes, a 32-bit int does have four bytes but each byte within it has its own address. So your extra `*4` is incorrect. You can only store 2^30 integers in 4GB of memory.

Comment: Okay i understand,thank you so much